# I have a colllection in mongoDb. I want to take first 10 docs in that collection and put it inside another collection in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named "Coll" in mongodb. I want to limit the collection to 10 and store that inside another collection.

I tried,

```
  db.Coll.insert(db.Maths_Sub_Bert.find({}).limit(10))
```

But this inserts only one value. How do I do this? Kindly help.

Comment: Instead of `insert` use `insertMany`.  And, for the `find` query add the `toArray()` at the end (after the `limit`) of it (the `insertMany` takes an array of documents as input).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in different ways, with same result.

Using Aggregation:

```
db.Maths_Sub_Bert.aggregate( [
  { $limit: 10 },
  { $out: "Coll" }
] )
```

Using the MongoDB Query Language (modified your query):

```
db.Coll.insertMany(db.Maths_Sub_Bert.find({}).limit(10).toArray())
```